# Create page using same slug as custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I am working on a site for a client who has custom post type called "practitioners" and several posts within this displaying info related to different practitioners.
I want to create a page with a slug "practitioners/page-name" but of course the site wont let me use this as a slug.

I tried creating a parent-page called practitioners (which wouldnt be used) and then a child-page with the slug "practitioners/page-name" and the slug worked fine, but then when I view the page I get "nothing found" because there is no practitioner called page-name.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is your CPT registered as hierarchical / does it need to be?

Comment: Please be considerate and follow up on **all** your previous questions. I have previously asked this of you but you ignored too. Please see [help] and [tour] to learn how sites like these operate. Please help keeping this site **AND** your questions constructive. Thank you :-)

Comment: Sorry @PieterGoosen I have now posted the resolution to my previous question.

Comment: @Adrian please answer Rarst's question and just remember one thing, there's a single Einstein in this world. If another Einstein appears we will surely gonna call him the Einstein Junior, or will number him as Einstein-2. Slugs should be unique otherwise they will collide.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam - Great way of looking at it, thanks.

Comment: @Rarst - Yes I think the CPT was registered as hierarchical. However I got the client to agree to a slightly different slug so that all the CPT's pages used a parent of "practitioners" and the pages I was trying to create could use "practitioner" without the S, it simplified things alot and users may not notice or even care!

Comment: @Adrian WP doesn't allow duplicate slugs withing hierachical or not–hierarchical post types, but does allow across types. Anyway if you had solved this please add your solution as an answer so the Q doesn't haunt site as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the client to agree to a slightly different slug so that all the CPT's pages used a parent of "practitioners" and the pages I was trying to create could use "practitioner" without the S, it simplified things alot and users may not notice or even care!